# How to avoid two bookings when one create booking at same time where the available booking count 1

Tags: spring

I am beginner to spring , now in my project we have method to make booking ,now if the available booking is 1 , when two user are trying booking at same time ideally only  one booking is allowed , but my application is allowing two bookings, now i made the method as synchronized now it is working fine, but synchronization concept belongs to JVM now if I am configuring my application in cluster mode there are different servers in different machines(so different JVMS), now synchronization wont work.
  Can any one please tell me the possible solution for this to restrict the booking,tell me solution from JAVA side and and also from DB side

Answer (score 3):

If the application may be deployed in cluster, the synchronized method will indeed not be enough.
You should rely on a node shared by all server instances : the DB.

You could use DB locking features, especially optimistic locking and pessimistic locking.
With them, you could avoid collisions resulting from concurrent updates to the same line by concurrent clients. 
Choose which one that matches better to your use case.

[Concurrency control in databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) extract:

> Optimistic - Delay the checking of whether a transaction meets the
> isolation and other integrity rules (e.g., serializability and
> recoverability) until its end, without blocking any of its (read,
> write) operations ("...and be optimistic about the rules being
> met..."), and then abort a transaction to prevent the violation, if
> the desired rules are to be violated upon its commit. An aborted
> transaction is immediately restarted and re-executed, which incurs an
> obvious overhead (versus executing it to the end only once). **If not
> too many transactions are aborted, then being optimistic is usually a
> good strategy.**
>
> Pessimistic - Block an operation of a transaction, if
> it may cause violation of the rules, until the possibility of
> violation disappears. **Blocking operations is typically involved with
> performance reduction.**

JDBC and JPA support both.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with ETags - optimistic locking mechanism.

It can be easily implemented with Spring. Please check official documentation.

Hope this will help.